# CBool vs System.Convert.ToBoolean in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please advise what the difference is between these two functions?

My understanding is that the former is a VB.net function but that the latter is not CLS compliant? So, I’m a bit confused.

Also, what is the best practice for using them?

Many thanks in advance,

Keith

Comment: They are functionally the same.  `CBool` is the legacy VB function while `Convert.ToBoolean()` is the NET form. The VB related articles tell you that the legacy VB forms provide `optimal interaction with Visual Basic code`.  However, some of them are limited - `CDate` and `CDec` are only able to work with the current culture.  `Cint` can be useful, the rest  less so the more complex the app gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference is that `CBool` evaluates an expression where as `Convert.ToBoolean()` takes an argument. Obviously you can easily get around this by using parenthesis and doing a `.ToString()` but `CBool` is just one of those *ease-of-use* features that `VB.NET` likes to implement.

Due to the whole expression reason `CBool` has the potential to be unsafe. Meaning an error in the expression would not be caught until run time. Where as if you supplied the same expression to `Convert.ToBoolean()` and it was invalid for the argument field the syntax parser would throw a fit and deny you from being able to build/run until you fix the issue.

Comment: Hi.
I think I understand. Do you mean that .ToBoolean does stricter type checking of its argument at compile time than CBool does on its expression at compile time? Therefore, it sounds like a good idea always to use .ToBoolean instead of CBool?
Thanks.
Keith

Comment: @KeithHoward Right. CBool could take an expression like `1 > 0` where as `.ToBoolean` needs an argument. Obviously in that example the expression would result in a boolean but there is the potential for an expression to not do so

Comment: OK, so .ToBoolean is stricter. I shall use that in the future. Many thanks. :)